# devtools::check() noting .lintr as a hidden file and directory

Tags: r, devtools, lintr

When I run `devtools::check()`, my build is noting my `.lintr` (located in the root directory) as being a hidden file most likely included in error. Is there anyway to prevent this from being noted on a check? It was not included in error, I need it to lint my package.

Comment: Add .lintr to your .Rbuildignore file